# How to order execution of classes in testng while running tests in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I have two tests to be run in parallel. Each test has two classes. Each class has several @test with priorities.
For eg:

```
Class A
   Method A1(priority=1)
   Method A2(priority=2)

Class B
   Method B1(priority=1)
   Method B2(priority=2)
```

Expected Output:

```
A1
A2
B1
B2
```

Actual Output

```
A1
B1
A2
B2
```

Note:- I have used `setPreserveOrder()` at Test level. Still wasn't able to get the expected output.
Please provide suggestions on this. Cedric Beust Any comments on this?

Comment: Why are you running these test in parallel if you want them to be executed in sequential order?  Thread priority only matters if you don't have enough CPU power.  How many CPUs do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's your case, but you could use `t.join()` method of `Thread` class.
Launched from the current thread *C* it means: "join *C* at the end of *t*, so that *t* must finish before *C* can run again"